# general topology, intersection of open sets

Tags: general-topology

under what conditions on a topology we have: $cl(U_1 \cap U_2)=cl(U_1) \cap cl(U_2)$ if $U_1,U_2$ is open

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you are asking only properties of the topology, must be a special one: That condition doesn't hold in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Edit: Take two open balls of radius one in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, one with center $(0,1)$ and the other with center in $(0,-1)$.

Comment: can I see your example in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The same. Replace $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition implies that disjoint open sets have disjoint closures, which in turn implies that the closure of an open set is open. This property is called "$X$ is extremally disconnected". It is well known that a metric space that is extremally disconnected is discrete (i.e. all subsets are open). I'm not sure whether any extremally disconnected space will obey the asked for identity, but it's pretty closely related condition anyway. So not too many spaces will satisfy it, though there are classical non-metrisable examples.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for any sufficient condition?

The $\subset$ inclusion is the one which could fail ($U_1=(0,1), U_2=(1,2)$), so if you ask the topology, for example, that every open would be closed, then your equality holds for every open sets $U_1, U_2$.

Comment: no, I  mean the weaker condition that equality is holding @chilen

Comment: do you mean a sufficient and necessary one?

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeees

Comment: You want the topology be finer enough such that $cl(U)$ would not be that much greater that $U$ (in order to $\subset$ always holds). I would try to proof that the topology being discrete is a characterization of your property. In my first commentary you have one implication.